# optional groups in regex to match different lines

Tags: python, regex

I have two files:

```
/c/desktop/test.txt#edit
/c/desktop/test.txt
```

I am using regex: `(.*desktop.*)(?:#.*)?`
it should match everything before and after `desktop` but leave anything which is from `#`, which may or may not exists in that line.

But it's either matching everything or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving what you want is by using the non-greedy operator `*?` in conjunction with the end of line operator: `(.*desktop.*?)(?:$|#.*)`

`.*?` says match as few characters as possible
`$|#.*` says match either the end of line or a `#` followed by characters.  This way, the `.*` from the first group does not match past the `#` because it is possible to match the pattern with fewer characters if the second group takes it.

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/7l1CQi/1